# memset does not work (C)

Tags: c, memset

```
char path[25500]= {};//iniatize
int visited[2500]= {0};//iniatialize
void fun();//protype

int main(){
    fun();
}

void fun(){
    visited[2300]=1;
    path[0]='9';
    printf("\n%d %s",visited[2300],path);
    memset(path,0,25500);//reset
    memset(visited,0,2500);//reset
    printf("\n %d %s",visited[2300],path);//to see if resetted
}
```

Outputs are:

```
1 9
1
```

I want to reset just like in the start. But as you can see, memset doesnot reset. My compiler is codeblocks.

Comment: Trust me: `memset` works. :)

Comment: Please allow me to offer some advice. Whenever you believe you've found a bug in a routine, especially a very commonly used routine such as `memset`, it's a very good idea to go back and give a very hard look at both your code and at the assumptions underlying your belief that you've found a bug. In over 40 years as a software developer I've found exactly *one* bug in a commonly-used piece of software. Every other time (and there have been a lot of them :-) that I've thought I've found a bug I've been right - it's just been that the bug has been in my thinking/understanding. Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis: As much as I wish that were sound advice, https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61095

Comment: By the way, did anyone else notice the 25500 in OP's code? I hope it's just a mistake transcribing the code into SO, but that definitely invokes UB.

Comment: Thank you.I have 2500 words with 5 char (alphabet), i made a advancey matrix of them to find wats between them and so i decided to make this path 25000. Is it wrong? I executed program 10 minutes ago but still it did not stop. Maybe because of it?

Comment: What do you suggest? Max path can be 2500x5=12500 letters + white spaces and "->", so maximum can be 25000.

Comment: Now i made 2500 but still it lasts very long to finish. 10 minutes passed but still printed no path.

Comment: @R it's still sound advice even if it's sometimes wrong. And then PHP's claim to fame is that the standard implementation is written by people with no idea about good software practices (your bug being another fine example of this at work).. bugs in gcc/libc are reasonably rare.

Comment: @R.. - thanks for presenting the counter-example, and for confirming my opinions about the sorry state of web development tools. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
memset(visited,0,2500);//reset
```

Visited is an array of integers, so this should be

```
memset(visited, 0, 2500 * sizeof(int))
```

Comment: Even better would be to use: `sizeof visited`.

Comment: Better alternative to your correction: `memset(visited, 0, 2500 * sizeof*visited)`. Still, BlueMoon has the best for a direct array.

Answer (score 3):

`memset` takes the number of *bytes* to set, not the number of elements. Change this line:

```
memset(visited,0,2500);
```

To something like this and it should work:

```
memset(visited, 0, 2500 * sizeof(int));
//or like this: memset(visited, 0, sizeof(visited));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
memset(visited, 0, 2500)
```

sets 2500 bytes to `0` from where `visited` points to.

However `visited` referrs to much more memory, namely 2500 times the size of its elements' type. That is `2550 * sizeof(visitied[0])`.

So do

```
    memset(visited, 0, 2500 * sizeof(visited[0])
```

to `0` out all of `visited`.

Your code uses the 2300th element. So assuming the size of an element to be `4` it is at offset 9200 to `visited`, your code only `0`-out 2500 bytes, so the 2300th element stays untouched by the call to `memset()`.

---

Referring to tthe comment below: Her a complete snippet on a robust way to use memset() in the OP's context:

```
#define VISITED_MAXIMUM (2500)

int visited[VISITED_MAXIMUM] = {0} /* line 3 */

/* Tons of code here . */

memset(visited, 0, VISITED_MAXIMUM * sizeof(*visited)); /* line X */
```

This construct above (line X) would survive without adjustements the change to dynamical memory allocation by replacing line 3 to be:

```
int * visited = calloc(VISITED_MAXIMUM, sizeof(*visited));
if (NULL == visited)
  exit(1);
```

Comment: Too verbose. `memset(visited,0, sizeof(visited))` is better

Comment: "*... is better.*": This depends. The approach you propose won't survive a change in the code to dynamically allocate `visited`. @icepack

Comment: True, but it will survive the change in array size - in contrary to your suggestion. It will also survive if `visited` becomes a struct, for example

Comment: If coded well the array size would be a constant or a run-time calculated value, and not a "magic-number" as in those snippets. @icepack I consider my solution to be more "robust".

Comment: It doesn't matter, 0 constants to maintain is better than 1

Comment: err ... "*`0` constants*"? @icepack An array size needs to be around, no matter how the array would get allocated.

Comment: I meant in this specific line with memset. Whatever work can be done by the compiler, should be left to it - unless there is a very good reason for not doing so.

Comment: Although I fully agree on "*Whatever work can be done by the compiler*" as per my updated answer, the "*very good reason*" in this case I feel is robustness. The *constructing* code (line 3) might be changed without adjusting the *using* code (line X). @icepack.

Comment: You're presenting one possible evolution scenario, but it's not necessary the correct one. The code may evolve in multiple ways and without having requirements and overall system view there is no reason to favor one change path instead of another. How about this change: from int visited[2500] the code will change to `struct visited {int data[2500]; int moreData[2500]};` to allow extension of the original algorithm